# Particle-hole statistics relation with superconductors

Tags: superconductivity, fermions, chemical-potential

I have a problem regarding the Fermi-Dirac (FD) functions and the relation between particles and hole.
The FD distribution for an electron is
$$ f^e(\varepsilon) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(\frac{\varepsilon-\mu}{kT})} $$
where $\varepsilon$ is the energy, $\mu$ the chemical potential and $T$ the temperature.

For holes the distribution satisfys $f^h(\varepsilon) = f^e(-\varepsilon) = 1- f^e(\varepsilon)$ (with $\mu =0$), but often when the distribution is related to a superconductor the distribution is written in the following way
$$ f^\alpha(\varepsilon) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(\frac{\varepsilon-\alpha \mu}{kT})}$$ with $\alpha = \pm$ for electrons/holes
(for instance in this
[paper](https://doi.org/10.1088/0953-8984/10/5/003) ([preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9708056)) (between eq. 11 and 12 in the text).
My question is that with that definition one does not seem to recover the properties of a hole distribution (that equals 1 minus electron), neither in (some if any) limit to a non superconducting situation.
How is this solved and what am I missing?